# Why zero derivative doesn't mean car is static?

Tags: calculus

I watched 3blue1brown about derivative paradox .

He asked that does car move when t=0 ?
Car move with

> $S = t^3$

And derivative is

> $3t^2 $

And his answer is :

"The issue is the question make no sense. It reference the Idea of change in moment but that doesn't actually exist.

That's just not the derivative measures.

What it means for the derivative of function $S$ to be zero is that the best constant approximation for the car's velocity around that point. For example if you look at an actual change in time what it mean for the derivative of this motion to be zero is that for the smaller smaller nudges in time this average velocity approach zero. (picture 1)

[image]

But that's not to say that the car is static. Approximating it's movement with a velocity of zero is after all just an approximation.

So whenever you hear people refer derivative as instantaneous rate of change a pharase which intrinsically oxymoronic I want you to think that as a conceptual shorthand for the best constant approximation for the rate of change . "

And my question came up :

Why did he say that when derivative is zero the car is not static?

And what does this part mean "Approximating it's movement with a velocity of zero is after all just an approximation ?

Comment: You cannot really think about speed at an isolated point in time, so what he means is probably that in every arbitrary small time frame around $0$ the car is moving.

Comment: Thank you. But why I cannot think about speed at an isolated point in time? because each point in time have their instant velocity.

Comment: Could you please edit your quotation of him to be exact? Judging by the grammar, you've dropped a few words that are probably important to his meaning. But I think his point is to be truly static for a nonzero amount of time requires zero velocity thought, and hence also zero acceleration (velocity's time derivative) and so on.

Comment: I think it's using static in a more general sense, in that something about its state is changing

Comment: Also just a warning, 3B1B is not fully rigorous (or even very close to rigorous sometimes) mathematics. His videos are great for a lay audience, but they do not always match mathematics in the classroom. I particularly found myself fairly displeased with his introductory calculus videos in this regard while generally greatly enjoying most of his other content.

Comment: Further to @CameronWilliams's point, for some reason 3b1b's focus is to show you how ideas were (or could have been) figured out, rather than presenting the polished version that emerged from that.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I agree apart from the part "His videos are great". I said it many times here , and I say it again : I watched many of those videos (for the sake of curiosity whether they are actually useful!) and the result was sobering. Even for a lay audience. It is your decision at the end , but it is better for you if you trust me.

Comment: A falling stone actually has a "momentary speed" , but it cannot actually be measured. The formula determines the "momentary speed" , but this is only a mathematical model. If we want to measure the speed , the smaller the distance is , the better will be our estimate of the "momentary speed". The situation is similar with a driving car.

Comment: @Peter.This is what I understand suppose car has acceleration = 2 if it is mathematical model when t=1 velocity will be 2 m/s but in real life maybe it will be 2.0001 m/s right? But why 3B1B said that zero derivative at t=0 doesn't mean car is static